# error mongo without mongod running first locally in win 10

Tags: mongodb, mongo-collection

I have this mongo.zip installed in my win 10.

I have set the environment path with bin.

Somehow whenever I start command line,
my mongo ***cannot start without*** mongod first.

```
C:\Users\asus>mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

but if I run `mongod` before `mongo`, mongo is running perfectly.

So, my question is: how do I running `mongo` without `mongod` locally.

PS. my compass is running and can connect to AWS cloud.

Please provide pictures if you can.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you, first of all, you have to know about the difference between them.

[**Mongod**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/index.html) is the process of MongoDB.

[**Mongo**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) is a shell. You can use it to connect and run any mongo command on any MongoDB.

So, your error means;

You are trying to connect your own MongoDB with typed `mongo`, because the default `-host` parameter is **localhost**. But your `mongod` process is not running. So you have to start it.

> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

`127.0.0.1:27017` equals **localhost**.

If you have MongoDB (mongod process) on AWS. You should connect with below command

```
mongo --host mongodb0.example.com:28015
```

Comment: so, it means: it won't run the local database just by typing ```mongo``` in shell? I should run both of them?

Comment: Not every time, just check out your service status and if stopped you have to run it. Use this code `service mongod status`

Comment: thank you! I can run just `mongo`, but not every time. I think you're right. It's because of the service status. Thank you!